# Position absolute element's width like it's container (in css)

Tags: html, css

So there is the following layout:

[image]

We are focusing at the 'SERVICEUSER' button and its submenu problem.

So is there a way to make the minimum width of the submenu (with position absolute) the same as its parent.

I have recreated the situation on this
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/lcristianiim/xschn0yw/3/).

So basicly what is needed is to make the .collection min-width same as the width of the `li`.

The html structure of this situation is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">SERVICEUSER</a>
    <div class="collection">
      <div class="item">Item-1</div>
      <div class="item">Item-2</div>
      <div class="item">Item-3</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The css of this situation is like this:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }

li { display: inline; }

a { background: green; }

.collection {
  position: absolute; // this is necessary for the situation
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Give `position: relative;` to the `li` element and give `min-width: 100%;` to `.collection`
You can position the `ul` absolutely if you choose and it will not affect either of those styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element positioned with "absolute" is contained in the flow of its closest relative parent. If you make `li` relative, you can set the width for collection.

```
li { display: inline; position: relative; }

.collection {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Edit: I added `white-space: nowrap` to allow the collection (subitems) to be larger than the main item.